# javascript or json expression to parse json to get a certain value

Tags: javascript, json

I need to be able to parse this json array/object for a value where an element matches a value.
For example, I wanted to get the value of $, where the @name = nameGreen.

```
{
      "startNode": {
        "result": {
          "node1": {
            "$": "A_Value"
          },
          "attribute-value": [
            {
              "@name": "nameRed",
              "$": "attribute1"
            },
            {
              "@name": "nameBlue",
              "$": "attribute2"
            },
            {
              "@name": "nameGreen",
              "$": "attribute3"
            },
            {
              "@name": "nameYellow",
              "$": "attribute4"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Getting the value of node1 was easy `console.log(['startNode'].result.node1['$']);` will get me the value of A_Value.

I'm just having problems writing logic for, 
1. when @name = nameGreen,
2. then get the value for $

Note: This json node is dynamic, so the @name and $ values will always change.

Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop through the actual values to examine them. For example,

```
var attrs = ['startNode'].result.['attribute-value']
for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
  if (attrs[i]['@name'] == 'nameGreen') ...
}
```

(Obviously you can write some nicer code to do this.)

I'd recommend you look for some libraries that help you extract this data in a better way, as it looks like you are parsing XML.

Answer (score 0):

[JSBin Example](https://jsbin.com/bocijov/1/edit?js,console)

Heres one way to do it, looping through "attribute-value" the array:

```
var a = d.startNode.result["attribute-value"];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i]['@name'] === 'nameRed') {
    console.log(a[i].$);
  }
}
```

Things to note:

- If a variable has a '-' in it, try using bracket notation as opposed to dot notation.
- Same with odd characters like `@`
- However, that is not required when using a `$` as you can see from the code above

Answer (score 0):

General function as required (ES6)

```
const getThing = (arr, key, test, match) => (
  arr.filter(el => (el[key] === test))[0][match]
);

var arr = obj.startNode.result['attribute-value'];
var out = getThing(arr, '@name', 'nameGreen', '$');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ggee3mz5/)

Or the same thing in more verbose ES5:

```
function getThing(arr, key, test, match) {
  return arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el[key] === test;
  })[0][match];
};
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p4n99y8g/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you could also use the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method of array objects or a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) for it to locate an "attribute-value" object before reading its `$` property:

```
var nodes = { ..... }; // the posted object.

var findObj = ( arrayOfObj, propName, propVal) => 
    arrayOfObj.find( (obj) => obj[ propName] === propVal );

var atr = findObj( nodes.startNode.result["attribute-value"], "@name", "nameGreen");

console.log( atr ? "$ for namegreen: " + atr.$ : "not found")
```

where `findObj` is a function to search `arrayOfObj` for an object with property `propName` with value `propVal`, and the arrow function supplied to `find` returns `true` or `false` for the match.